# Converting a string into a JSON obj or array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following string:

```
{
    blogid:"12345",
    date:"09.09.2014",
    uid:"0",
    author:""
}
```

Could anybody give me an idea on how to convert this into a JSON structure or a javascript array and then get the value of each key, say:

```
blogid="12345"
uid="0"
etc.
```

Comment: already looks like a JSON

Comment: This looks like a perfect JSON, No need to convert.
Just initialize a varible/object and assign it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval` like this

```
var str = '{blogid:"12345",date:"09.09.2014",uid:"0",author:""}';
var arr = eval('('+str+')'); // '(' and ')' are mandatory!
console.log(arr['blogid']); // prints 12345
```

But be sure that string is safe for eval https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval Check `Don't use eval needlessly!` chapter

Safer way would be to use `JSON.parse` but the problem is that function is not available for IE 8/9 (however you can use script from http://www.json.org/js.html instead)

Comment: eval works! JSON.parse would return "SyntaxError: Unexpected token b" because blogid is not quote by ""

Comment: Yup, if you have blogid:"12345" and not "blogid":"12345" you dont have valid JSON

Answer (score 2):

This may be helpful,

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Then you can get the value directly like blogid,date,date.

or you can use this also,

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"blogid":"12345"}');
alert( obj.blogid=== "12345" );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is json only. To get values of each key you can do like this :

```
var sample ={blogid:"12345",date:"09.09.2014",uid:"0",author:""};
```

Now:

```
sample.blogid //12345
sample.uid //0
// and so on...
```